# Retrieve data from model via controller using ajax in cakephp 3

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am using cakephp 3 to develop a website. Iam quite new to this. I am trying to retrieve data from the function getSelectedItineraryData() in my ItinerariesController.
Here is my controller code:

```
public function getSelectedItineraryData()
    {
        $selected_itinerary = @$this->request->data('id');
        $locationdata = $this->Itineraries->find('locationdetails', [
            'selected_itinerary' => $selected_itinerary
        ]);

     return json_encode($locationdata);

    }
```

This uses a custom finder method located in the model file ItinerariesTable.

```
public function findLocationdetails(Query $query, array $options)
    {
        return $this->find()
            ->distinct(['Intineraries.id'])
            ->matching('Itineraries', function ($q) use ($options) {
                return $q->where(['Itineraries.name IN' => $options['selected_itinerary']]);
            });
    }
```

This is the ajax request which makes the call to the controller:

```
function getwypts(callback){
         $.ajax({
        url: "/Itineraries/getSelectedItineraryData/" + selected_i,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
        id: selected_i
        },
        //async: false,
        success: function(result, status) {
            var dayint = 1;
            alert(result);
            itins = JSON.parse(result);
            var day_arr = JSON.parse(itins.day_array);
            var json_day_list = JSON.parse(itins.json_day_data);
            $('#temp_dir_array').val(JSON.stringify(day_arr));
            $('#sel_id_name').text(itins.name);
            start_n = itins.start_name;
            end_n = itins.end_name;
            var tempp = JSON.parse(itins.day_array);
            waypt_obj.start = itins.start;
            waypt_obj.end = itins.end;
            waypt_obj.waypt = itins.arr_intin;
            for (dayint = 0; dayint < json_day_list.length; dayint++) {
                temp11 = tempp[dayint];
                $("#itin_list").append('<div id="itinerary_item_' + (dayint + 1) + '"  value="' + dayint + '"><a  href="#" style= "border: 2px solid red;list-style-position: inside; margin: 5px" class="list-group-item testing"><input type="hidden" id="viewport_wp_item" value="' + tempp[dayint][0] + '" ></input><div class="alert alert-success"><b>Day  ' + (dayint + 1) + ' of Trip (Overnight stay at ' + json_day_list[dayint].overnight + ')</b></div><div id="" class="alert alert-info"><b>Places Visited: ' + json_day_list[dayint].places + '</b><br>' + json_day_list[dayint].desc + '</div></a></div>');

            }
            if(callback) {
            callback();
            }
        }
    });

    }
```

The issue I have is that this request returns an empty result. It seems that this is because the custom finder methood does not return a correct response. What is wrong in my controller?
Or is the error coming from somewhere else?
Thanks in advance, been trying for hours on end now.

Comment: Have you tried just doing the standard `debug()` during different parts of the process to see how far it gets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place it to your controller. Hope your problem will be solved!

```
public function getSelectedItineraryData($ID)
{
    $selected_itinerary = $ID;
    $locationdata = $this->Itineraries->find('locationdetails', [
        'selected_itinerary' => $selected_itinerary
    ]);

 return json_encode($locationdata);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but without the return.  Instead of that i used
`echo json_encode($locationdata);
exit();`
Why is this?

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392600/whats-the-difference-between-return-echo-json-encode-in-php

Comment: Thank you, it does solve half the remaing issue, but there's one more thing, the code won't work without the `exit();` part. I understand this is to exit the function, but why wouldn't it exit the function at the end anyway? please help!